# How can I require DCO-signing for my GitLab CE repo?

Tags: gitlab

I want only want to accept merge requests where every commit has a "signed-off-by" component, as required by the [Developer Certificate of Origin](https://developercertificate.org). Similar to [probot/dco](https://probot.github.io/apps/dco/) for GitHub.

How can I configure my GitLab repo (on my own GitLab CE instance, not GitLab.com) to reject merge requests where this rule is not followed?